# Android translate navigation drawer item

Tags: android

I have a navigation drawer menu with diferent items in a listview. This item´s names are in arrays.xml like this one in values-es and other one in values:

```
<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item>One</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
    <item>Four</item>
</string-array>
```

I have done a method to translate the app but this items not change when a different language is selected. The others textview work perfect. What I am doing wrong? it is possible to translate an array item?

Answer (score -1):

Try this, but do not forget initially define variables.

`<string-array name="nav_drawer_items">
    <item>@string/one</item>
    <item>@string/two</item>
    <item>@string/three</item>
</string-array>`